# SQL Filter rows on date difference

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL 5.6
Have a table which I query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT client, date_buy
FROM tickets
ORDER BY client, date_buy
```

Which gives me almost the result I need:

```
------------------------------
client          | date_buy
-------------------------------
0027847524333  | 2018-06-13 16:03:43
0027847524333  | 2018-06-13 16:13:01
0027847524333  | 2018-06-18 22:03:01
0033652356025  | 2018-06-16 17:22:56
00353857861869 | 2018-08-13 17:37:56
```

What do I need to add to query so I could leave only clients where it has been more than 24h between orders?

Desired result:

```
------------------------------
client          | date_buy
-------------------------------
0027847524333  | 2018-06-13 16:03:43
0027847524333  | 2018-06-18 22:03:01
0033652356025  | 2018-06-16 17:22:56
00353857861869 | 2018-08-13 17:37:56
```

Update: I would like to exclude repetitive sales for one customer that happened less than 24 hours each other.

Comment: If there are more than one client in one day, you include the first one?

Comment: No, I will include everyone. I would like to exclude repetitive sales for one customer that happened less than 24 hours each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `group by` with `DATE(date_buy)` and `client` instead of `DISTINCT`.
Then get `MIN(date_buy)` be your `date_buy`

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE tickets(
  client varchar(50),
  date_buy datetime
);


insert into tickets values ('0027847524333', '2018-06-13 16:03:43');
insert into tickets values ('0027847524333', '2018-06-13 16:13:01');
insert into tickets values ('0027847524333', '2018-06-18 22:03:01');
insert into tickets values ('0033652356025', '2018-06-16 17:22:56');
insert into tickets values ('00353857861869','2018-08-13 17:37:56');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT client, MIN(date_buy) date_buy
FROM tickets
GROUP BY DATE(date_buy),client
ORDER BY client, MIN(date_buy);

| client         | date_buy            |
| -------------- | ------------------- |
| 0027847524333  | 2018-06-13 16:03:43 |
| 0027847524333  | 2018-06-18 22:03:01 |
| 0033652356025  | 2018-06-16 17:22:56 |
| 00353857861869 | 2018-08-13 17:37:56 |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ix3mwiwRjDZRdvKaNR6LFJ/0)

Comment: @SimonOsipov No problem glad to help :)

Comment: One more question: How then I could calculate the time difference between the first 0027847524333 and second? Or if there is more than 2?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this :

```
    SELECT * 
FROM tickets t_1, tickets t_2
where t_1.client = t_2.client
and DATEDIFF(hour, t_1.date_buy, t_2.date_buy) < 24
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `date_buy` column is of [smalldatetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/smalldatetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) type (if not, you can easily [parse](https://database.guide/parse-vs-cast-vs-convert-in-sql-server-whats-the-difference/) it to be).

Here's one way you could implement the query. Start by creating a table of all *later* clients where it has been less than or equal to 24 hours since a previous order:

```
CREATE TABLE helper AS
SELECT DISTINCT b.client AS cl
FROM tickets AS a, tickets AS b
WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, a.date_buy, b.date_buy) <= 24 AND a.client = b.client
```

Then, select all other clients from `tickets`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT client, date_buy
FROM tickets, helper
WHERE client <> cl
ORDER BY client, date_buy
```

You can obtain the same result by [deleting](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp) entries from `tickets`, though this would mutate the original table. This solution **takes into account hour differences across the day change**.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using LAG

```
SELECT client, date_buy
FROM (SELECT client, date_buy, 
        DATE_ADD(IFNULL(LAG(date_buy, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY client ORDER BY client, date_buy ASC), '1900-01-01 00:00:00'), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) prev_date
      FROM tickets) sub
WHERE date_buy > prev_date
```